# Pickle Mock/MagicMock object with __name__ attribute

Tags: python, pickle

Mock/MagicMock doesn't have a default `__name__` attribute, I added it manually.

When running the following code snippet:

```
import pickle
from mock import MagicMock

m = MagicMock()
m.__name__ = 'my name'
m.__reduce__ = lambda self: (MagicMock, ())

print(m.__name__)

b = pickle.dumps(m)

pickled_m = pickle.loads(b) 
print(pickled_m.__name__)
```

I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/.../.pyenv/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 716, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute %r" % name)
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute '__name__'
```

How can I instruct pickle to serialize the `__name__` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is not with `pickle`, your `MagicMock` class has a custom implementation of `__getattr__` magic method, which  raises an `AttributeError` exception for some conditions. To make a proof for that, the following code:

```
import pickle
class A():
  a = 10

a = A()
a.__name__ = "A"
ap = pickle.dumps(a)
na = pickle.loads(ap)
print(na.__name__)
```

will output:

```
'A'
```

So the `__name__` is being  pickled and unpickled with no problems.